# Mobile music playback on android phone keeps buffering

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, android, 9.10, streaming

I have copied some music to a Ubuntu synced folder on my Karmic machine and I have the Ubuntu One Android app installed on Android 2.2 phone.

When listening to music I get frequent breaks whilst the music is buffering, even with full signal. Every other music streaming service such as "Last FM" and "BBC iPlayer" are fine.

What is going wrong? mp3s should not have trouble buffering over a good 3g signal.
I have set cache size to 200mb but I cant find a buffer size. 
Is it my mp3s? they are usually in the order of 320kb/s

This is a breaker for me if there is no solution which is a massive shame as I like the principal of the software. **Cheers**

Answer (score 2):

could you install "alogcat" from the android market, run the application and hit this problem, and then send me the log?  martin.albisetti[at]canonical.com.
That'll give us some insight into what's happening.

We've had a ton of updates this past week, some of which could of addressed your issue. Could you try again?